# Clang: typeid and exception throwing through DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, clang, throw, typeid

Suppose I have a program, which has a dynamic-link library (DLL) and an executable.

`DLL.hpp`:

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
class Apple {};

DLL_EXPORT void                  ThrowApple ();
DLL_EXPORT const std::type_info& GetAppleTypeinfoFromDll ();
```

`DLL.cpp`:

```
#include "DLL.hpp"

void                  ThrowApple ()              { throw Apple<void> (); }
const std::type_info& GetAppleTypeinfoFromDll () { return typeid (Apple<void>); }
```

`Program.cpp`:

```
#include "DLL.hpp"
#include <assert.h>

int main ()
{
    try {
        ThrowApple ();
    } catch (const Apple<void>&) {
        // OK
    } catch (...) {
        assert (false);
    }

    assert (typeid (Apple<void>) == GetHAppleTypeinfoFromDll ());
}
```

`DLL_EXPORT` is a macro that compiles to "export" in the DLL, and to "import" elsewhere. On MSVC this is achieved with `__declspec (dllexport)` and `__declspec (dllimport)`, and on clang it is `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` when exporting, and nothing when importing.

My expectations are written in terms of `assert`'s. This program works perfectly when compiled with MSVC, but both assertions fail with clang. Is there a compiler/liker option that I should use to make this work with clang?

We can assume that the whole program (all DLLs and the EXE) is maintained by the same company, and they are in full control of all build parameters for all components.

Comment: It is not safe to throw an exception over the DLL boundary. There is no guarantee that the caller will be able to handle the exception properly, so just don’t do it, ever.  `type_info` doesn’t work over the DLL boundary, either. The type information inside the DLL is different than the type information inside the EXE.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: What do I risk, when I throw an exception over a DLL boundary? How does one identify classes in a program of several DLLs, if not with `typeid`?

Comment: You risk crashing the EXE when it tries to handle an exception it can't handle. Or worse, if it doesn't handle the exception at all.